# No gradients provided for any variable: ['generated_image:0']

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I working on neural style transfer project. when in final step when I train the model it is showing error

I am adding two images one content image and second style image to produce the new image which is content image with style of style image

> No gradients provided for any variable: ['generated_image:0'].

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
@tf.function()
def train_step(generated_image):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    a_G = vgg_model_outputs(generated_image)
    J_style = style_cost(a_S, a_G)
    J_content = content_cost(a_C, a_G)
    J = total_cost(J_content, J_style, alpha = 10, beta = 40)

  grad = tape.gradient(J, generated_image)
  optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, generated_image)])
  generated_image.assign(tf.clip_by_value(generated_image,clip_value_min=0.0, clip_value_max=1.0))

  return J
```

```
epochs = 5000
for i in range(epochs):
    train_step(generated_image)
    if i % 250 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {i} ")
    if i % 250 == 0:
        image = tensor_to_image(generated_image)
        imshow(image)
        image.save(f"output/image_{i}.jpg")
        plt.show()
```

full stack trace

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3a761c39189b> in <module>()
      1 epochs = 5000
      2 for i in range(epochs):
----> 3     train_step(generated_image)
      4     if i % 250 == 0:
      5         print(f"Epoch {i} ")

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 764             *args, **kwds))
    765 
    766     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-22-71263e1538e0>:11 train_step  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, generated_image)])
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:630 apply_gradients  **
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py:76 filter_empty_gradients
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['generated_image:0'].
```

general image:

```
generated_image = tf.Variable(tf.image.convert_image_dtype(content_image, tf.float32))
noise = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(generated_image), 0, 0.5)
generated_image = tf.add(generated_image, noise)
generated_image = tf.clip_by_value(generated_image, clip_value_min=0.0, clip_value_max=1.0)
```

i don't know what is wrong? please help!

Comment: please share the full stack trace in code snippet not in quotes

Comment: i added the full stack trace

Comment: Looks like an issue with `generated_image` not being formatted properly. can you show the code that generates it?

Comment: added general image gerneration code

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run the code from this [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/home/welcome) on your own computer, as I got exactly the same problem after trying to do it.
The problem is that when you pass the generated_image to the train_step, it is of the wrong type. If you check the `type(generated_image)` it is likely to be

`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`,

while it should be:

`<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>`.

You can easily fix this by adding the line
`generated_image = tf.Variable(generated_image)`
This line of code was originally there in a testing cell and you may have deleted it by mistake when cleaning up the code (this is exactly what I did). The best place is to add this line just after the last line of generated_image that you have posted.